# How to make a box around a section

Tags: sectioning, framed

I'm trying to put a box around a section, both the title and the contents. I've found ways of doing one or the other, but not both.

```
+-----------------------+
| Title                 |
|                       |
| content of section    |
| ...                   |
+-----------------------+
```

Something like the above, a single box around both the section title, and the section content.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try the [mdframed package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
\section{This is a framed section}
This is the text.
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image: mdframed]

Comment: Tried that.  Ended up with strange results.  Some sections had to lines, others did not.  Some had left lines, others did not.  Some had bottom lines, others did not.  No single section had four lines all the way around it.  Actually, on closer look, the lines do go all the way around, but such a thin line that Adobe Acrobat does not render the line in all cases.  How can I make the line thicker?

Comment: Use something like `\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=5pt]` (see the [mdframed package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) for details).

Answer (score 10):

Another option, using the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,colback=white,colframe=cyan,width=\dimexpr\textwidth+12mm\relax,enlarge left by=-6mm]
\section{A framed test section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using ConTeXt. First a text background is defined using
[`\definetextbackground`](https://github.com/mojca/context-gitorious/blob/origin/tex/context/base/anch-bck.mkvi#L308-L330).
In contrast to a `\framed`, the text background permits page breaks. All
options except `location` are optional. The background is then hooked into the
chapter.

```
\setuppapersize [A6]  %% only for the screenshot

\definetextbackground
  [sectionbackground]
  [location=paragraph,
   rulethickness=2pt,
   topoffset=2em,
   leftoffset=2em,
   corner=round,
   radius=1cm,
   background=none]

\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [before=\startsectionbackground,
   aftersection=\stopsectionbackground]

\starttext
  \startchapter [title=Lorem ipsum dolor…]
    \input knuth
  \stopchapter
\stoptext
```

[image: screenshot]